# Prevent Play! Framework from compiling after changing js files

Tags: javascript, compilation, playframework

I am developing an application with Play Framework. Whenever I make any change to JavaScript files, Play starts the compilation. I hoped I will prevent this by moving them to the public/javascripts folder but the behavior is the same. The reason why I want to do this is to speed up my development process. The compile time is long and it slows me down a lot, because I am checking the results of my work in the browser quite often.

Is there any way to prevent play from compiling after changing the js files?

Comment: Looks the same question of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704951/play-framework-no-need-to-compile